# Does AppLinks Work With an Ad Hoc iOS Install

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I am using iOS 9.3.3 and have the latest version of Facebook installed.

I have my app installed under the Ad Hoc provision. I have tested my URI scheme with plain links in safari and my app opens perfect and deep links how I want.

However when I try a link in the Facebook App it never opens my App, just loads the page in the Facebook webView. I have double checked my meta tags via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I can see all the needed meta tags are there e.g. al:ios:url, al:ios:app_store_id, al:ios:app_name and correct URI scheme supplied.

I have tried setting the web fallback option to false:

`<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />`

Now when I click the link inside the Facebook app I get an install app prompt even though I have the app installed (under Ad Hoc). Which begins to make me think Facebook thinks it's not installed as it's an Ad Hoc install and not from the app store?

If I go to the App Store it also says install, not open etc.

Can we test with Ad Hoc installs? I am going a bit mad with trial and error debugging, but obviously want to check if it should or should not work with an Ad Hoc install before I just chance it and publish to the App Store.

Has anyone had experience with this? Or is something majorly wrong perhaps.

Just to note, I have it fully working with the Android version of my App.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Facebook :). You've got it exactly right: Facebook has completely broken their own AppLinks standard on iOS, and there have been multiple open bugs about it for many months. It still works on Android currently, but that's about the only place.

The best workaround currently is to open the webview (as you are doing) and then allow the user to trigger the app deep link from within there. At Branch.io, this is one of the primary usecases for our [Deepviews](https://dev.branch.io/features/deepviews/overview/) feature.

Comment: Many thanks for your response, at least I can stop banging my head against the wall for now. Hopefully Facebook update their docs or create some magical fix soon.